# Social Network, how is build "You have new unread message" architecture

Tags: ajax, architecture, social-networking, web-architecture

For example, when we have new message on http://facebook.com or http://gmail.com, site gives us signal about this, and this happened without  refresh page. how it works?  I Imagine this so:

some  Jhon  is registered user on site.

There is javascript code, which every 10 seconds sends AJAX request to messages table, for check: in table, has or not  unread messages for john (architecture, how marking ready / unread messages, here not important), if Yes,  site give signal to Jhon "You have several new messages".

Tell please, I am closer to the truth or not? If yes, I have also one questions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern sites we use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) which enable the server to push information to the browser with less overhead and no delay. That's what's used on SO.

But as [some browsers still don't support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), we must sometimes fall back to a pull-loop as the one you describe.

On the server it may be handled with a queue instead of database queries at each browser request. But there are probably many different implementations on this point.